# When does the Picard iteration give a power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I been trying to figure out when or if it is possible to see that the Picard i.e  iteration $x_{k+1}=x_{0}+\int f(t,x_{k}(t))dt$ leads to a power series expansion of the solution $x$.

In simple and concrete cases I can see it. But it would be nice to be able to think about this iteration as a general way of obtaning a power series solution theoretically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you meant $$x_{k+1}(t) = x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t f(\tau,x_k(\tau))\,d\tau.$$
If $f(t,x)$ is a polynomial in $t$ and $x$, ie. $$f(t,x) = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m a_{ij}t^i x^j,$$
then we can prove inductively, that each $x_k(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$, if we start with $x_1(t) \equiv x(t_0)$. Obviously $x_1(t)$ is a polynomial of order zero. Now suppose we know that $x_\ell(t)$ is a polynomial. Then we have
\begin{align*}
 x_{\ell+1}(t) &= x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t f(\tau,x_\ell(\tau))\,d\tau \\
&= x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m a_{ij}\tau^i x^j(\tau)\,d\tau \\
&= x(t_0) + \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m a_{ij} \int_{t_0}^t \tau^i x^j(\tau)\,d\tau \\
\end{align*}
Since $x_\ell(\tau)$ is a polynomial, so is $\tau^i x_\ell(\tau)$, and so is its integral. By induction, $x_k(t)$ is always a polynomial. So the solution to your initial value problem $x(t)$ is the limit of the $x_k(t)$, so a limit of polynomials, that you could consider a power series.

Comment: Ah nice, one should be able to extend this to analytic $f$ right? But do you think one get it for continuous or differentiable $f$? If we just go via some density argument and only have it depend on the coefficients? That is what I considered but got stuck.